# Move a bootstrap input element further down the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to move the class "top" (my search bar/button) half way down the page but am having no luck using bottom or anything else. Currently it's just stuck at the top. I would also like to make the search box bigger but am not sure how to.

```
<div class="row top">

    <div class="col-md-2">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a hero">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
              </span> Search
            </button>
          </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
    </div>

</div>
```

Also I'm sure there's a better way to center my search box instead of adding columns either side to appease the grid system but I have no idea, any tips?

Here's what it currently looks like:

[image: Here's what it currently looks like]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by moving the class half way down? Are you trying to move the search bar so it's vertically centered?

Comment: You don't need the empty divs <div class="col-md-2"> </div> You could just use col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 so it adds the 2 column spacing on the left hand side

Comment: @FedericoGiust Yep precisely, I'd like the search bar to be lower down the page, thanks for the offset tip, I knew there had to be an easier way

Answer (score 4):

Try adding your own class to the div

CSS

```
.top-buffer { margin-top: 30px;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="row top top-buffer">

    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a hero">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
              </span> Search
            </button>
          </span>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: that's what I did, using my own class 'top' but nothing happens.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/08wst3xm/1/ Seems to be working  for me. Alter the margin in the css part.

Comment: Ah never mind it is working, was just me being silly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks Cohan for this solution, I never thought this was as simple as this